# Lineman spec-ci in jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, linemanjs

I have installed nodejs, npm, lineman, jenkins, and phantomjs on red hat.

I am trying to run a jenkins job that just runs lineman spec-ci to run my test-em tests. When I run this command as the jenkins user on the terminal, it runs. Unfortunately, when I run this command as a job in jenkins, it fails:

node: error while loading shared libraries: libhttp_parser.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

This error comes up even if I try to run npm install with the jenkins job.

The jenkins service is running under the user jenkins and if I run whoami during the jenkins build it outputs jenkins.

Any idea why I can run npm and lineman commands as the jenkins user but it fails when run as a job?

Comment: More information will probably be needed, like your Jenkins config, os version, etc.

Comment: Red hat, Jenkins 1.609.3, npm 1.4.28, node v0.10.35. The jenkins service is set up to run as the jenkins user. Nodejs and npm were compile but the paths have been added to the jenkins user path and I also added it to the path global variable in the jenkins application.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up running printenv and found a variable associated with libraries. I added that variable to jenkins -> configure -> global properties.